How to configure Serilog to keep the most recent log without a numeric suffix when using file rolling?
I'm using Serilog's file sink for logging in a .NET 8 application. I have configured the file sink to roll over when the file size limit is reached, but the naming convention is problematic for my use case. Here's my current configuration:
.WriteTo.File(
    path: "C:/Logs/MyApp.log",
    fileSizeLimitBytes: 5242880, // 5 MB
    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
    retainedFileCountLimit: 5
);

With this setup, the log files are named as MyApp.log, MyApp_001.log, MyApp_002.log, etc. However, the file without a numeric suffix is not the most recent file. For example, after some logging activity, the files might look like this:

MyApp.log - older logs
MyApp_001.log - older logs
MyApp_002.log - older logs
MyApp_003.log - most recent logs

I need the most recent log file to always be named MyApp.log so that I can provide direct links to the latest log without having to adjust for a rolling numeric suffix. How can I configure Serilog to reverse the naming convention, so the current log file remains without a suffix and older log files are the ones that get numerically suffixed upon rolling?

I can't elaborate on an answer right now, but have you tried checking the hooks property of the WriteTo.File() overload?

The desire for such a rippling rename rolling strategy akin to that of other loggers is covered in detail in https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/40

Serilog.Sinks.File won't (and shouldn't) do that
But someone forked it and did it anyway (but I would still not do that) https://github.com/dfacto-lab/serilog-sinks-file/issues/26

